# Transform one type to another

Tags: java, generics

I need to improve this code:

```
final String valueString = value.toString();

if (Path.class.isAssignableFrom(destinationType)) {
  fixedValues.put(key, Paths.get(valueString));
} /* ... as above, for other types ... */ {
} else {
  fixedValues.put(key, valueString);
}
```

So I decided to implement a Transformer-like which converts a type `X` to another `Y`.

I created this interface

```
public interface Converter<S, D> {
  D convert(final S source);

  Class<D> getDestinationClass();
  Class<S> getSourceClass();
}
```

so when I need to implement a conversion I implement this interface

```
public class StringToIntegerConverter implements Converter<String, Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer convert(final String source) {
    return Integer.parseInt(source);
  }

  @Override
  public Class<Integer> getDestinationClass() {
    return Integer.class;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<String> getSourceClass() {
    return String.class;
  }
}
```

(example of String -> Integer)

Now, to convert the types I have another class `Converters` which contains inside a Table (Guava Table with two keys) where all the converters are stored.

```
private final static ImmutableTable<Class<?>, Class<?>, Converter<?, ?>> converters;
```

And has the method `convert`

```
public <S, D> D convert(final Class<S> source, final Class<D> destination, final S value) {
    return destination.cast(converters.get(source, destination).convert(source.cast(value)));
}
```

The error is

```
incompatible types: S cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?
```

at `source.cast(value)`

because I store them in the map with `?` so i'm stuck. I don't know how can I fix this. I got the feeling that it's not possible, but i'm posting to see if i'm wrong.

I read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s05.html) by Spring, but it's a different way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you are trying to achieve is possible:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <S, D> D convert(final Class<S> source, final Class<D> destination, final S value) {
    final Converter<S, D> converter = (Converter) converters.get(source, destination);

    return destination.cast(converter.convert(source.cast(value)));
}
```

**However, the code by its nature cannot guarantee type safety. You have to guarantee, that the 3 elements put into `Table` are compatible.**

Comment: Oh, I understand what you did. I didn't thought something similar. Now it compiles. Now I test it, thank you

Comment: It will work, but if you mess up the converters table, then you will get runtime ClassCastExceptions.

Comment: Then it's ok, because it means that the programmer who created the implementation failed to implement the methods. Because the instace and the table is filled with reflection (reading getSourceClass/getDestinationClass)